# couchbase Expression must depend only on group keys or aggregates

Tags: couchbase, sql++

why I get this error message on my query ?

```
"Expression (`L`.`product_id`) must depend only on group keys or aggregates.
```

Query:

```
SELECT 
P.product_id as PID,

L.product_id as LikedPID,
COUNT(L.likedAt) as likes
FROM  products P 

INNER JOIN products_likes L
ON P.product_id = L.product_id
WHERE  P.product_id='3221132' GROUP BY P.product_id;
```

Comment: It looks like you're joining between buckets. This is fine and it will work, but based on the names of your buckets, I suspect you don't need to do this. Think of a bucket as a database. If you have a "product" service and a "product likes" service, it might make sense to have two databases. But if product and product likes are part of the same service/microservice, you might consider combining them together into one bucket. (This gets even easier with Couchbase 7, which includes scopes & collections functionality).

Answer (score 2):

The reason for this error message is because you are using an aggregate (`COUNT`), but not everything else you are projecting in your SELECT is aggregated or included in the `GROUP BY`. (This is true of every SQL I've used, by the way, not just Couchbase's N1QL). If you want to group by both product IDs, you'll need to change your `GROUP BY`:

```
GROUP BY P.product_id, L.product_id
```

Or you could omit the `L.product_id as LikedPID,` from your `SELECT`.